What is the IR limit of $U(1)$ gauge theory?
It seems that the IR (infrared) limit of some theories with massless particles is not a CFT (conformal field theory), for example, free $U(1)$ gauge theory. Does it mean there is no IR fixed point for those theories?

Expl. ur abbr’s.

The pure gauge theory is free. Do you mean $U(1)$ gauge theory with matter (so QED) or in $d \neq 4$? See https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5385

Yes. I have just heard that this theory has a scaling invariant fixed point, but not a conformal fixed point.@ConnorBehan
